# How can i fill up empty column value if all other row values are filled in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have the following problem: In my dataset it happens that missing values appear in the column "ID". The values in the ID column are always the same or None.  If there are no other missing values in the row, the value of the ID should be filled with the unique value of column 1. In this case "1". If there are other missing values the ID row value should no be filled.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [None, "1", None, "1", None],
        "A": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg", "ham"],
        "L": ["A54", "A12", "B84", "C12", None],
        "G": ["X34", "C84", "G96", "L6", "C74"],
    }
)
print(df)
shape: (5, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ ID   ┆ A    ┆ L    ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ null ┆ foo  ┆ A54  ┆ X34 │
│ 1    ┆ ham  ┆ A12  ┆ C84 │
│ null ┆ spam ┆ B84  ┆ G96 │
│ 1    ┆ egg  ┆ C12  ┆ L6  │
│ null ┆ ham  ┆ null ┆ C74 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

expected outcome

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ ID   ┆ A    ┆ L    ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ foo  ┆ A54  ┆ X34 │
│ 1    ┆ ham  ┆ A12  ┆ C84 │
│ 1    ┆ spam ┆ B84  ┆ G96 │
│ 1    ┆ egg  ┆ C12  ┆ L6  │
│ null ┆ ham  ┆ null ┆ C74 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't edit the post of @jqurious here the solution that worked for me:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.all(pl.exclude("ID").is_not_null()))
      .then(pl.col("ID").backward_fill().forward_fill())
      .alias("ID")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like:

When all columns (excluding `ID`) are not null then take the filled `ID` column:

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.all(pl.exclude("ID").is_not_null()))
     .then(pl.col("ID").backward_fill().forward_fill())
)
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ ID   ┆ A    ┆ L    ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ foo  ┆ A54  ┆ X34 │
│ 1    ┆ ham  ┆ A12  ┆ C84 │
│ 1    ┆ spam ┆ B84  ┆ G96 │
│ 1    ┆ egg  ┆ C12  ┆ L6  │
│ null ┆ ham  ┆ null ┆ C74 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Yes you got the point of the logic. But when I use your solution I got this error message: TypeError: 'WhenThen' object is not iterable

Comment: @Horseman I ran it exactly as-is and it worked.  I'm on 0.16.7

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I am on 0.16.8.

Comment: I solved it. I needed to add .alias() after the .then() expression: `df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.all(pl.exclude("ID").is_not_null()))
    .then(pl.col("ID").backward_fill().forward_fill()).alias("ID")
)`

Comment: It works for me on 0.16.8